# Angular (observable): update interval in merge

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm wondering how to change the interval value in my merge when I update my data in my table :

```
 merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page, interval(this.delay))
      .pipe(
        startWith({}), // ... fetch data
```

I need the table isn't update while the dialog is open when I click on a row, so I'd like to put a big timer in the interval (or if you have a better solution, or if you know to obtain the max date in TS it's welcome too ^^')

```
  selectRow(row: GithubIssue) {
    this.selection.select(row);
    this.delay = 10000000;

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
        this.selection.clear();
        this.delay = 30000;
      });
  }
```

I've made a stackblitz repo if it can help : [repo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sj1syp?file=src/app/table-http-example.ts)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an interval stream that can be toggled on and off via a toggle subject. Let's say there's `keepUpdating$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);` in the global scope.

```
toggleInterval$ = keepUpdating$.pipe(
  switchMap(update =>
    update? interval(this.delay) : EMPTY
  )
);

merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page, toggleInterval$)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}), // ... fetch data
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
selectRow(row: GithubIssue) {
  this.selection.select(row);
  this.keepUpdating$.next(false);

  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.selection.clear();
      this.keepUpdating$.next(true);
    });
 }
```

---

Side note:

It's probably a bad design choice to poll your backend/database like this. If you want to update your table in realtime, it's a bad user-experience to have your table hiccup (with a loading animation) while waiting for any update. Instead, you should consider performing the update in the background and pushing the update to the table once it's ready to display.

Then there is no need for an interval to check, you just push changes as they're ready.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't put a loading animation in my project. The stackblitz was the code from angular material I've taken ideas from and it was easier to take it than put my project anonymous.
I'll look for the push idea, I've never impletemented this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with the `skipWhile` operator. Something like

```
.pipe(
  skipWhile(() => this.dialogRef && this.dialogRef.getState() === MatDialogState.OPEN)
)
```

Comment: I like the nice idea but I haven't found how to get the state. Thank you anyway :)